# "getPendingNotificationRequests" always return 0 swift

Tags: swift, notifications, localnotification

I want to fetch pending local notification which I added. But getPendingNotificationRequests is always return 0. The code is below.

```
var weekdayArray : [UNNotificationRequest] = []
    center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { requests in
        for request in requests{
            weekdayArray.append(request)
        }
    })
```

How can I fetch notifications which I added?

Comment: The code does not *return* anything.